# Name of natural comparison function in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, callback, comparison, intersection

I want to do the intersection between two multidimensional arrays in php 5. E.g:

```
$a = array(array(), array(1), array(2));
$b = array(array(), array(0), array(2));
```

I naturally try:

```
array_intersect($a, $b)
```

But it gives me **Notice** because of array to string conversion. As a workaround, I want to precise the comparison function using uintersect:

```
array_uintersect($a, $b, function($x, $y){return $x == $y ? 0 : ( $x < $y ? -1 : 1 );})
```

And it works. But this is kind of ugly. My question is simple, is there a **built-in** natural comparison function which works on array and which I could use as callback function like in:

```
array_uintersect($a, $b, 'natcmp')
```

Thank you!

Comment: I understand exactly what you want. Did not see you this array_uintersect job function? Another function you want to use it more?

Comment: @BuseGönen I am not exactly sure of what you mean, but of course I can create my own function 'natcmp', but I expect there is a simpler way. And this will be use only for intersection, not for sorting or whatever.